# Calculating the average using names on a pivot table

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, worksheet, vba

I'm trying to have the pivot table calculate the average number of employees underneath each supervisor for a specific region. However pivot tables are unable to average out text strings. In the example below, within one region I have 5 supervisors but they all have different numbers of employees under them, some have 1 or 2. But all together there are 7 employees for that region. I need it to average out the number of employees per supervisor: so 7/5 = 1.4 would be the average. Is there any way you can create a count of employee divided by the amount of unique supervisors using a pivot table?

[Number of Supervisor to Employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Isg.jpg)

Comment: You could add another column to your data using the `AVERAGEIF` function and then also use an average on the field in the pivot table

Comment: I would have to do it by adding an extra column to the original data using COUNTIF to count how many times a supervisor's name was repeated

Comment: Hi guys, it is important that this needs to be in a pivot table format just because i need to see the whole span of control of each supervisor. and each supervisor has a different grade level and I need to find the average of grade level 10, 11, etc.

I want to know how can I manipulate the pivot table to calculate how many employees on average are per supervisor. But I can't get the pivot table to count employees and divide it with how many unique supervisors there is. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: In an ideal world I wish I could manipulate the pivot table by putting supervisor name in the row field, supervisor grade in columns field, and calculate the average employee in the Value data field. But that seems to be non-achievable because the employee names column are text strings. how can I get this to appear on the pivot table?

Comment: @CallumDA33  AVERAGEIF function will not average out words, only number values.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe. Yes COUNTIF will help me find how many times a supervisor repeats itself (which tells me how many employees they are in charge of) but I need a pivot table that will show me the average of every supervisor in the same grade how many employee they have.

Answer (score 0):

OK well not very elegant I know but this would do it. Add a helper column which works out the fraction of a supervisor available to each employee (e.g. 2 employees per supervisor = 1/2, 3 employees = 1/3 etc.) starting in D2:-

```
=1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$20,A2,$C$2:$C$20,C2)
```

Then you can put the sum of these and the count of any column into a pivot table, putting Region as the row variable, and simply a manual formula to work out the ratio starting in J2:-

```
=IFERROR(I2/H2,"")
```

[image]

Note:- You can use GetPivotData to get the totals from the pivot table if you prefer. You could also use an array formula to list the distinct values of Region and not use a pivot table, but the pivot is quicker.